# How do typecast a type in Go

Tags: go

I am trying to make a recursive routine that prints the elements of a complex json

```
func printMap(m map[string]interface{}) {
for k, v := range m {
    typ := reflect.ValueOf(v).Kind()
    if typ == reflect.Map {
        printMap(v)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(k, v)
    }
} }
```

but I get a build error 
can use type v ( type interface {} ) as type map[string] interface{}

Is there a way to type cast it or someway I can get it to work?

Comment: What line does your error actually come from? The simple answer is, you have some type that is being represented by the empty interface `interface{}`. If the underlying type is in fact a `map[string]interface{}` then you can do a type assert on it `v.(map[string]interface{})` in order to get the correct type for subsequent statements. If the underlying type isn't a `map[string]interface{}` then you need to look at your input because it differs from what the statements down the page expect.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

```
func printMap(m map[string]interface{}) {
  for k, v := range m {
    m, ok := v.(map[string]interface{}) // <-- assert that v is a map
    if ok {
        printMap(m)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(k, v)
    }
  }
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/S6k9DicmVY)